# Difference beetwen default.vim and /etc/vim/vimrc

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc

What is the difference between `$VIMRUNTIME/default.vim` and `/etc/vim/vimrc`?

Why is `$VIMRUNTIME/default.vim` started first? 
Shouldn't `/etc/vim/vimrc` leave first?

(Debian 9)

Comment: Could you add some information on which Linux flavor and version you are using? In Debian-based systems, e.g., `/etc/vim/vimrc` sources the settings from the `$VIMRUNTIME` directory.

Comment: Done...debian 9

Comment: What does The Fine Manual say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/etc/vim/vimrc` is a system-wide default Vim configuration added by the corresponding package maintainers (e.g. the Debian folks for the *vim-common* APT package). It represents the opinion of the distribution's maintainers about good (and secure) defaults.

For a long time, Vim itself didn't provide any default configuration; instead, it just shipped with an example ([`:help vimrc_example.vim`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#vimrc_example.vim)) to get individual users started on their personal configuration (i.e. `~/.vimrc`). Many people did not like that Vim starts with conservative defaults (for *vi* compatibility), and the "helpful" system-wide configuration also caused confusion (as Vim has so many configuration possibilities and flexibility), and so with Vim 8.0 a default configuration in the form of [`defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) was [added](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/version8.txt.html#incompatible-8).

Your question hints at confusion with that configuration. In general, if the defaults don't work for you, **do all your customization in your user's `~/.vimrc`**, and leave any system-wide configuration alone. Those should only make uncontroversial changes (like `:syntax on`), so that should not interfere, but most option changes can also be undone by your `~/.vimrc`.

In terms of the order of configuration reads, [`:scriptnames`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Ascriptnames) shows what scripts got read in which order, and [`:help initialization`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#initialization) has all the gory details.

Comment: So, is **default.vim** first launched which in turn launches `/etc/vim/vimrc`...correct?

Comment: I read that guide ... but `/etc/vim/vimrc` is not really mentioned

Comment: As I said, it depends on your particular system. Check `:scriptnames` for the ordering, or maybe start Vim with `--cmd 'set verbose=2'` to see what's happening in detail.

Answer (score 4):

File `/etc/vim/vimrc` is the so-called "system" vimrc file (it should be listed as so in your `:version` output.)

`$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` is the "defaults" file, which was only introduced in Vim 8.0 (at least, that was the first non-patch release to include the feature.)

File `/etc/vim/vimrc` is controlled by the Linux distribution, so Debian or Red Hat, etc. will ship Vim initialization they find is relevant for your distribution there.

File `defaults.vim` is loaded automatically **only if you don't have a user vimrc file.** So only if your user is missing a `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc` file. If you do have one of these files, then `defaults.vim` will **not** be loaded automatically, though you might want to do it **from your vimrc.**

The system vimrc file is **always** loaded and it's always loaded **first**. (Well, unless you pass Vim command-line options telling it not to load the vimrc files, such as `vim -u NORC` or `-u NONE`, in which case it isn't loaded.)

After the system vimrc is processed, then it's turn for your own vimrc file, or `defaults.vim` if your own doesn't exist.

Now, there are two important caveats here!

First is that `defaults.vim` might have been disabled (more like neutered) by your distribution. Some distributions (namely Debian) weren't too happy about Vim shipping a `defaults.vim` file that would enable settings that users upgrading from previous versions weren't expecting.

So this was solved by having the Vimscript code in `defaults.vim` check whether a variable named `skip_defaults_vim` has been set. If it is, then `defaults.vim` will bail out early on and you won't really see its effects. (Note that the script will still appear under `:scriptnames`, since it does get to run, it just finishes very early.)

Since the only thing running before `defaults.vim` is the system vimrc file, that's the place where `skip_defaults_vim` can be set. So check whether your distribution is setting it, if it is, then you won't really get the effects of `defaults.vim` even when the file is being sourced.

Second caveat, and a point of frequent confusion, is when you first create a new vimrc file for your user. Then you go from having all the settings in `defaults.vim` loaded to having none of them. Which is quite visually apparent, since it typically means you won't have syntax highlighting enabled anymore, which is pretty much in your face, you can quickly notice the difference.

The recommendation here is that, when you first create a vimrc file, you should source `defaults.vim` from it, so you'll keep the features from it and then you can add your own customization later.

You can do that by adding these two lines to the start of your vimrc file:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

Notice it's also unsetting `skip_defaults_vim`, which means this will activate the `defaults.vim` settings even on Linux distributions that have decided to disable the effects of that file.

The `vimrc_example.vim` file shipped with Vim (which is provided as a template to use to create your own vimrc) includes a line that sources `defaults.vim` at the top.

For more information, see:

- [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim)
- [`:help initialization`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#initialization)
- the actual [`defaults.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/defaults.vim) shipped with Vim
- [`:help :scriptnames`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Ascriptnames)